# D3: How to implement horizontally responsive SVG elements?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

It is quite straight forward to implement responsive SVG elements like below.

```
<div id="chartId"/>

var svg = d3.select("#chartId")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 600 400");

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("fill","blue")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500);
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qtm2xLrp/)

The following takes place when the window size is shrank.

**Before shrinking**

[image]

**After shrinking**

[image]

As can be seen the rect angle is horizontally and vertically responsive.

***But, how can I implement an SVG element that is only horizontally responsive and the following takes place?***

[image]

One option would be to redraw the SVG element every time the window size is changed, but I would like know if there is more sophisticated solution available.

Comment: Is your question aswered? Or did we misunderstand what you want?

Comment: I think this question is clear.

Answer (score 1):

The preserveAspectRatio attribute determines the scaling and alignment used to fit the viewBox in the svg. When preserveAspectRatio = "xMinYMin meet", content is scaled uniformly (i.e. horizontal and vertical scaled at same ratio). When preserveAspectRatio = "none", content is scaled non-uniformly. In your code, change...

```
.attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
```

to...

```
.attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none")
```

Comment: It's still responsive horizontally and vertically after changing that

Comment: Setting "preserveAspectRatio" = "none" will cause non-uniform scaling of the viewBox to the svg element. However, since you did not specify a width and height of the svg element there is still the question of how the browser scales the svg element to fill the svg's parent's width. Some testing suggests that some browsers use non-uniform scaling while other browsers use uniform scale of the svg element. You can address that issue by explicitly set the svg element width and height (e.g. svg.attr("width", "100%").attr("height", "400")) like in ocket-san's answer.

Comment: guys, you are not answering the question

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, I was quite into the responsive D3, I am a bit sluggish now, but here is an answer anyway. And it is not so sophisticated. Just put '%' for the width dimension of your svg, and a fixed one for the height.

Do mind that when using '%', the actual dimensions are in function of those of the parent element. You need to take this into account.

Here is the code i took from your fiddle and adjusted it:

```
var svg = d3.select("#chartId")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", "100%")
            .attr("height", "200");


svg.append("rect")
    .attr("fill","blue")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("width", '100%')
    .attr("height", '100%');
```

It works, i tried it, but I am just not sure if it really is what you want...